# I get a BSOD while trying to train a CNN on jupyter notebook with the stop code IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, bsod

I get a BSOD while trying to train a CNN of about 33k images and 7 classes on jupyter notebook with the stop code IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL. What does the stop code mean and how can I fix this. If this is hardware related, I currently have a 2060 and 16 gb of ram. My computer will either crash with above stop code, or it will completely freeze, requiring me to completely cut the power to the computer to turn it off. The batch size of my epochs is 32, and the data is loaded using

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
data_dir,
validation_split=0.2,
subset="training",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size)
```

and

```
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
data_dir,
validation_split=0.2,
subset="validation",
seed=123,
image_size=(img_height, img_width),
batch_size=batch_size)
```

with the training being

```
epochs = 20
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

I updated my drivers which allowed me to run my model for 20 epochs, but any more epochs led to the crashing/freezing again. Please help.